# Как сделать в Unity3d скролл объектами?

Tags: алгоритм, unity3d

[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Нужно сделать, что бы по нажатию на стрелочки, листались объекты.(Кол-во объектов будет всегда изменяться. Кружочек, который сейчас выделен - обводиться красным.
Как реализовать такую функцию? Юзаю новый Unity UI (4.6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Создаете новый объект Panel и переименовываете его в ScrollRect.
2. Добавляете на него компоненты ScrollRect и Mask.
3. Создаете еще один объект Panel в качестве дочернего объекта ScrollRect и переименовываем его в ScrollContent.
4. На этот объект вешаете компоненты Horizontal Layout Group и Content Size Fitter.
5. В Content Size Fitter выставляете Preferred Size.
6. Теперь в качестве дочерних объектов к ScrollContent можно добавлять Ваши объекты, если они UI. На каждый из них нужно повесить компонент Layout Element и указать ему MinWidth/MinHeight и PreferredWidth/PreferredHeight. Если объекты - не UI, то придется решить вопрос с позицией и порядком отрисовки.
7. Создаете два объекта Button. В иерархии располагаете их рядом с ScrollRect, как Вам нужно. На кнопки вешаете скрипт и именуете его, например, ButtonScroller. Не забудьте добавить using UnityEngine.UI;
8. В скрипте задаете поле float Speed для инспектора, которое будет регулировать скорость скролла, и поле ScrollRect _scroll - на него в инспекторе перетаскиваете ScrollRect.
9. Добавляете в скрипт свойство public bool Pressed { private get; set; }
10. Добавляете на кнопки компонент Event Trigger и задаете там события Pointer Down и Pointer Up. Событию Down указываете только что созданное свойство Pressed и ставите галочку (true), событию Up тоже указываете, но галочку не ставите.
11. В методе Update() проверяете if(Pressed), если нажата, то сдвигаете на текущем кадре: _scroll.horizontalNormalizedPosition += Speed * Time.deltaTime;

Если Вам не нужен функционал ScrollRect, то компонент ScrollRect нужно удалить. А двигать будете Transform дочерней панели (ScrollContent), например, при помощи Translate(). В этом случае еще придется самостоятельно установить ограничения для скролла.

По поводу выделения, если встроенное выделение Вас чем-то не устраивает, то можно сделать его вручную, опять же, при помощи скрипта и Event Trigger'а.

Так же замечу, что это только вариант решения, не обязательно жестко ему следовать.